# Perl incompatibility issue with each in a hash of hashes - 5.14 → 5.8.8

Tags: perl

The following code works fine with Active Perl 5.14.2:

```all-perl
my %hzones = ();
#%hzones= (
#    'zone1' =>  {
#                  'ns1' => 'ip1',
#                  'ns1' => 'ip2',
#                  },
#    'zone2' =>  {
#                  'ns1' => 'ip1',
#                  'ns2' => 'ip2'
#                  }
#);

foreach my $k1 ( keys %hzones ) {
    debug("# $k1",$d); 
    while ( my ($key, $value) = each($hzones{ $k1 }) ) { # Problem is here   217 
        while ( my ($nsname, $nsip) = each(%$value) ) { 
            debug("## $nsname , $nsip",$d);
    }
    # Creation de la zone et ajout dans infoblox
    $session->add(createZone($k1)) or error("Add zone for ".$k1." failed: ", 
        $session->status_code(). ":" .$session->status_detail());
    }
}
```

Now, if I try to use this code on RedHat 5.3 with Perl 5.8.8, I have the following error:

```
Type of arg 1 to each must be hash (not hash element) at
  ./migration-arpa.pl line 217, near "}) "
Execution of ./migration-arpa.pl aborted due to compilation
  errors.
```

**Question**: How do I fix this error? How do I traverse my hashtable?

Comment: Perl 5.7 is an *ancient* **development** release. Don't use it.

Comment: Red Hat 5.3 came with Perl 5.8.8 as standard (see http://vault.centos.org/5.3/os/i386/CentOS/). If you're running 5.7 then that means that someone has downgraded your version of Perl to a development (i.e. unstable) version of Perl. Really, don't use that for any serious work.

Comment: He said he's using 5.8.8 in the post. The subject must be a typo. Fixed.

Comment: Updated subject to reflect that greater perl in question is 5.14, not 5.12.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What Quentin said, but you could try replacing

```
each($hzones{ $k1 })
```

with

```
each(%{$hzones{ $k1 }})
```

which dereferences the hash ref.

Comment: Support for automatic derefencing of hashrefs was [added in Perl 5.14](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html#Syntactical-Enhancements).

Answer (score 3):

The ability to do pass a reference to `each` (`each($hzones{ $k1 })`) was [introduced](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html#Syntactical-Enhancements) in 5.14.0. Before that, one had to pass a hash (`each(%{ $hzones{ $k1 })`). That still works, and it will continue to work.

So, to be backwards compatible, use

```
each(%{ $hzones{ $k1 })
```

instead of

```
each($hzones{ $k1 })
```

Note: Passing a reference to `each` is marked as experimental, and I consider it buggy since it doesn't work with all hashes.

Comment: If it's experimental to pass a reference to `each`, what would be the best alternative to use without `each` ?

Comment: @Yohann, The only alternative (while still using `each`) is to pass a hash, as shown.

Comment: I was very excited about it, and now I agree, there are too many odd cases. I attempt never to use it. Unfortunately I accidently forgot a dereferencing `%` before a scalar once, the code worked, so I released ... and broke everything before 5.14. Oh well, easily remedied, but lesson learned.